# The task of using itertools

Tags: python, algorithm, task, python-itertools

Put + signs between some digits of 12345678910111213...N to make the sum of M.
The input is two positive integers N and M.
Conclusion: correct examples per line.

Examples:

1. Input: 5 15.
   Conclusion: 1+2+3+4+5=15
2. Input: 4 46.
   Conclusion: 12+34=46
3. Input: 15 1117614.
   Conclusion: 12+3+4567+891+01112131+4+1+5

But the third example won't work, so please tell me what to do.

```
from itertools import product

def find_expression(n, m):
    nums = [str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
    for p in product(['', '+'], repeat=n-1):
        expr = ''
        for i in range(n-1):
            expr += nums[i] + p[i]
        expr += nums[n-1]
        if eval(expr) == m:
            return expr
    return None

n= 15
m= 1117614
expression = find_expression(n, m)
if expression:
    print(expression + '=' + str(m))
else:
    print('No valid expression found.')

print(find_expression(5, 15)) # Output: 1+2+3+4+5
print(find_expression(4, 46)) # Output: 12+34=46
print(find_expression(15, 1117614)) # Output: 12+3+4567+891+01112131+4+1+5
```

Comment: If you print all `expr` values, you will observe that you jump from `12+3+4567+8910+11+12+13+14+15` to
`12+3+4567+89+101112131415`. Looks like n-digits numbers are not splited...

Comment: Are there any limits for N and M?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that the answer requires `10`, `14`, and `15` to be split, but your code only allows for the `+` to be inserted either side of a whole number.

You'll need to change your `nums` variable to something like `''.join([str(n) for n in range(1,n+1)])` and change your `for` loop to iterate over the length of the whole string as opposed to the number of numbers (i.e. 1 to 15 has 21 characters, not 15).